# Flask-Uploads Module

Tags: flask-uploads

I am using `Python 3.8.2`. I am trying to create a project by using the `Flask-Uploads` module.

When I try to run it, I get error:

> "no module named flask.ext.uploads"

I then tried to install this module again with upper case letters like `Flask-Uploads`, but I still have the same problem.

I was wondering if there's a problem with the latest Python version I am using?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you have a too old `Flask-Uploads` version.

`Flask-Uploads` has not seen an update on PyPi since 2016.

I created a fork of the library, in order to fix some errors and continue development:

https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Reuploaded/

You can use the new library as a drop-in replacement, that means, you do not have to change a single line of code.

Also, you have to import from `flask_uploads` instead of the obsolete `flask.ext.uploads`.