# How to import flask-reuploaded module

Tags: python, flask, flask-uploads, flask-reuploaded

I was trying to use flask-uploads module but I found in the thread:

[Flask-Uploads Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60872429/flask-uploads-module)

That I should go with flask-reuploaded module to fix the error:

`import name 'secure_filename' from 'werkzeug' (c:\users\gabri\desktop\shop\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\__init__.py)`

It says in the thread that I don't have to change a line of code but I dont know how to import the module properly, because when I try

`from flask_uploads import UploadSet`  I get

`No module named 'flask_uploads'`

and if I try any variation of  `from flask-reuploaded import UploadSet`  It cannot find the proper library to import

I didn't find anything about it in documentation can you please help?

Comment: I updated the below answer and I hope this helps - please do not hesitate to ask further questions.

Answer (score 2):

The package for `Flask-Uploads` on PyPi is broken since February 2020 when `Werkzeug` changed its API, thus the error message you see.

You can either install `Flask-Uploads` directly from GitHub or instead of `Flask-Uploads` install `Flask-Reuploaded` which is a compatible drop-in replacement.

https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Reuploaded/

As of Oct 5th, 2020, there is no "get started" guide on `Flask-Reuploaded`s README page, that's correct.

As stated in the https://flask-reuploaded.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ and as you tried already, you just have to install `Flask-Reuploaded` and then e.g. do a `from flask_uploads import Uploadset`.

Please note it is `from flask_uploads...` not `from flask_reuploaded`. That is done on purpose to be 100% compatible with `Flask-Uploads`.

When you experience an error like `No module named 'flask_uploads'` this strongly indicates one of two possible problems:

- you did not install `Flask-Reuploaded`
- you installed it, but not in the same **virtual environment** as `Flask`

Please make sure to install both packages into the same `virtual environment`.

To prove it... do a `pip freeze` - for me that would look like the following...

```
~/Projects/example_flask_reuploaded took 10s 
❯ pip freeze
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Reuploaded==0.3.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

That all said - I will update the README section of `Flask-Reuploaded` as soon as possible.

**Update, January 18th, 2021**

I have updated the README of `Flask-Reuploaded` with more clear information how to get a project started.

https://github.com/jugmac00/flask-reuploaded/blob/master/README.rst